# const overrideOptions = metaConfig.config ?? {}; issue while running in bamboo

Tags: node.js, ckeditor5, postcss-loader, cosmicjs

```
const overrideOptions = metaConfig.config ?? {};
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50                                                 ^
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50    
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50        at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50        at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/CMSG-NLFSNAPSHOT19-JOB1/kiwi/src/main/ux/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/utils.js:18:20)
30-Aug-2023 15:37:50        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
```

Throwing this error while build is happening in bamboo
I am using postcss-loader version as "7.3.3"

**The issue is due to not being able to pasrse ?? in latest node version in webpack 5**

Comment: The issue is due to not being able to pasrse ?? in latest node version in webpack 5

Comment: this issue is happening because of latest postcss-loader ...installed old one and got resolved